# FastScrolling ListView with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I would like to have my Xamarin.Forms ListView (XAML) FastScroll.
I already wrote a CustomRenderer for Android and set `Control.FastScrollEnabled = true;`. But unfortunately this is not enough to make it work. As described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/layouts/list-view/part-2-populating-a-list-view/#Enabling_Fast_Scrolling) the Adapter needs to implement `ISectionIndexer`.

In my case the Adapter on the ListView does not (`HeaderViewListAdapter`).
Does anyone have an Idea how this problem can be solved? I already tried to write a wrapper for the Adapter, but can't get it work (gets never called because I think a ListView's Adapter can not be switched after it has been set once).

Thanks!

Comment: By `In my case the Adapter on the ListView does not (HeaderViewListAdapter).` what do you mean? [Here is a video about fast scroll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gtrlw79sW44)

Comment: That the `HeaderViewListAdapter` does not implement `ISectionIndexer`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to get it working. I had to create a CustomView in XF that inherits ListView. And in a CustomRenderer I was able to create a new Adapter that implements `ISectionIndexer`